# Sonar null pointer voilation while reading excel file

Tags: java, collections, apache-poi

Sonar giving null pointer violation for below line of code.

cell1.getRow()

Please could you help us to resolve this issue.

```
 private List<InvalidUploadedExcelData> validateSheet(Sheet sheet) throws Exception {

    InvalidUploadedExcelData ITD;
    ArrayList<InvalidUploadedExcelData> returnedInvalidTestDataList = new ArrayList<InvalidUploadedExcelData>();
    Cell cell1, cell2, cell3;
    for (int i = 1; i < sheet.getRows(); i++) {
        cell1 = sheet.getCell(0, i);
        cell2 = sheet.getCell(1, i);
        cell3 = sheet.getCell(2, i);

        if ((cell1 == null || StringUtils.isEmpty(cell1.getContents().trim()))) {
            ITD = new InvalidUploadedExcelData(TITLE_TEST_ID, "Row-" + (cell1.getRow() + 1) + " Column-" + (cell1.getColumn() + 1) + " is missing");
            returnedInvalidTestDataList.add(ITD);
        } else if (!isValidProperty(cell1.getContents().trim())) {
            ITD = new InvalidUploadedExcelData(TITLE_TEST_ID + ":" + cell1.getContents().trim(), "Row-" + (cell1.getRow() + 1) + " Column-" + (cell1.getColumn() + 1) + " is not valid");
            returnedInvalidTestDataList.add(ITD);
        }

    }

    return returnedInvalidTestDataList;
}
```

Comment: Removing unimportant stuff, `if (cell1 == null) { cell1.getRow(); } `. Can you call *any* method on a `null`?

Answer (score 0):

The following lines will cause a `NullPointerException` if cell1 is actually null as you check for null in the if-condition, but you still enter the branch and then access `cell1.getRow()` in there.

```
   if ((cell1 == null || StringUtils.isEmpty(cell1.getContents().trim()))) {
        ITD = new InvalidUploadedExcelData(TITLE_TEST_ID, "Row-" + (cell1.getRow() + 1) + " Column-" + (cell1.getColumn() + 1) + " is missing");
```

You will need to get the row/column information differently in this case to be safe.